# How can I get rid of "scanning for btrfs filesystems" at start-up?

Tags: boot, 14.04, filesystem, btrfs

When I start up my computer, it says: "scanning for btrfs filesystems".
I do need the btrfs-tools, but my btrfs filesystems are on a removable disk which is disconnected at start-up.

Scanning for btrfs filesystems adds a considerable delay to system start-up and seems unnecessary. How can I avoid it?

I have installed:

ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Btrfs v3.12

Comment: Now it does not add any delay.

Answer (score 1):

When you install `btrfs-tools`, some hooks come with this to "install" btrfs support in your initramfs that come in boot to your system.

the files are

```
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/btrfs
```

(you can check with `dpkg -L btrfs-tools`) one alternative can be that after you install btrfs-tools, **delete** these files and after this rebuild your initramfs from /boot with

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and with this your boot process will avoid to preload the btrfs module and try to detect any module on boot. You will need to do this any time that `btrfs-tools` get installed/updated in your system. And you are going to need to do a `modprobe btrfs` just in case, before plug-in your external disks formated with btrfs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried searching for «btrfs» in /boot, and when I removed all the lines containing «btrfs» from config files there, no such message appears again.
This may appear some sort of a rough workaround, though.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com. You have provide a detailed solution and steps, such as which config files you've edited and where in those files.